# Swift error when adding annotation to map

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, annotations, mapkit

I get the error: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION for the last two lines of this function. also earlier in my code I get the users location and want to use that for the location for the pin. Thanks in advance!

```
@IBAction func makeEvent(sender: UIButton)
    {
        self.pointAnnotation1 = MKPointAnnotation()
        self.pointAnnotation1.title = "Event"
        self.pointAnnotation1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.986, longitude: -78.945)
        self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation.coordinate
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)
    }
```

Comment: did you try to print self.pointAnnotation.coordinate ? or  self.pointAnnotation? it is probably nil where do you get it?

Comment: this code for me work perfectly         `let pointAnnotation1 = MKPointAnnotation()
        pointAnnotation1.title = "Event"
        pointAnnotation1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.986, longitude: -78.945)
        let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: pointAnnotation1, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        self.map?.centerCoordinate = pointAnnotation1.coordinate
        self.map?.addAnnotation(pinAnnotationView.annotation!)`

Comment: is `self.mapView` Nil?

Comment: Im still getting the same fatal error @ReinierMelian

Comment: You should add annotation in viewDidLoad method.